# Transform system of equations while leaving solution set invariant?

Tags: equation-solving

Consider the example system of equations

```
syst==res
```

where

```
syst={x + 2 y + 3 x y, 1 + 4 x + y};
res={0 , 0};
```

Solving for the solutions of this system, we obtain

```
Solve[syst == res, {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> -(1/2), y -> 1}, {x -> -(1/3), y -> 1/3}}

Now, imagine that we want to transform the system of equations with an `x,y` dependent transformation. For example

```
trafo = {{1 + x, 1 - y}, {1 + x, -1 + y}};
```

Unfortunately, acting with `trafo` introduces new solutions into the system which have not been there before

```
Solve[trafo.syst == res, {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> -1, y -> 1}, {x -> -1, y -> 3}, {x -> -(1/2), y -> 1}, {x -> -(1/3), y -> 1/3}}

Therefore, I wonder if there is a criterion I can use to find such `x,y` dependent transformations that will preserve the initial set of solutions without introducing new ones? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: This seems to be a math rather than Mathematica question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the transformation must be invertible in order not to introduce new roots.  For instance, `trafo` is not invertible for `x = -1` and introduces additional roots involving `x -> -1`.  Likewise,

```
trafo2 = {{1 + x, 1}, {-1, 1 - x}}
Det[trafo2]
(* 2 - x^2 *)
```

is not invertible for `x -> Sqrt[2]` and `x -> -Sqrt[2]`, and introduces corresponding additional roots

```
Solve[trafo2.syst == res, {x, y}]
{{x -> -(1/2), y -> 1}, {x -> -(1/3), y -> 1/3}, {x -> -Sqrt[2], 
  y -> 1/31 (23 + 30 Sqrt[2])}, {x -> Sqrt[2], y -> 1/31 (23 - 30 Sqrt[2])}}
```

However, `trafo1 = {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}` is invertible and introduces no additional roots

```
Solve[trafo1.syst == res, {x, y}]
(* {{x -> -(1/3), y -> 1/3}, {x -> -(1/2), y -> 1}} *)
```

Comment: Do `x,y` dependent transformations exist that are invertible on the whole complex plane?

Comment: @Kagaratsch  I do not think so.

Comment: "Invertible", for this purpose, means it must have a polynomial inverse. Something like `{{4 + 3 x - y - x y, -3 - 6 x - 3 x^2 + y + 2 x y + x^2 y}, {3 - 
   y, -2 - 3 x + y + x y}}`. In the terminology above, the determinant must be a number (so Cramer's rule will give a polynomial matrix inverse).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to invertible transformations, transformations which are not invertible will not introduce new solutions if either

1. the `(x,y)` at which they are not invertible are in `sol = Solve[syst == res, {x, y}]`,
2. the null space of the transformation does not contain `syst`.

E.g.

```
trafo = DiagonalMatrix[syst];
```

is not invertible when

```
ysol = Flatten@Solve[Det[trafo] == 0, y]
```

> $$ \left\{y\to -4 x-1,y\to -\frac{x}{3 x+2}\right\} $$

or

```
MatrixForm@trafo /. ysol[[1]] // Simplify
MatrixForm@trafo /. ysol[[2]] // Simplify
```

> $$ \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -2 \left(6 x^2+5 x+1\right) & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) $$
>   $$ \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 0 \\
>  0 & x \left(4+\frac{1}{-3 x-2}\right)+1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) $$

with null spaces

```
n1=NullSpace[trafo /. ysol[[1]]]
n2=NullSpace[trafo /. ysol[[2]]]
```

> {{0,1}}
>
> {{1,0}}

which do not contain `syst` if `syst!=0` and

```
Solve[n1.syst == 0, y]
Solve[n2.syst == 0, y]
```

whose solutions exactly match those for where `trafo` is not invertible. Therefore, the null space of the transformation does not contain `syst`, satisfying criterion 2, unless `syst` is trivial. But if `syst` is trivial, `(x,y)` will be in `sol`, satisfying criterion 1. Check that new solutions aren't introduced:

```
Solve[trafo.syst == res, {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> -(1/2), y -> 1}, {x -> -(1/3), y -> 1/3}}